# Visual Studio 2010 - .Sln file when clicking on .csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I can open my project by double clicking on the .csproj file. It opens fine and it doesn’t generate a .sln. If I copy the same project to a virtual machine and do the same it opens but creates a .sln file.

I really don’t need a solution I would prefer to only work on a single project.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio always creates a solution.  If it cannot find one in the same folder as the .csproj file then it will create one itself, based on what it can reverse-engineer from the project file content.

The solution is hidden by default if the solution only contains one project.  Fixing this is recommended: Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General, "Always show solution" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks! I´ll keep it enabled from now on. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is always a solution, even if you don't see it. There's a setting that determines whether the solution is visible when there is only one project.